# GR setup for casandra in webscale environment

Tags: cassandra, openshift, f5

We are trying to do GR setup for our application which has casandra pods(deployed within application namespace) deployed in two different clusters on two
sites of webscale environment. All external routing from the cluster is done via F5/spk.

How can we setup casandra data replication via F5/SPK between primary and secondary .

Multus is not allowed on platform ...

Comment: What's GR short for? 

Comment: Global redundancy .. There should not be any delta between primary and DR database both should be always in synch